# Xamarin tutorial on how to sign in / up and store data online

Tags: c#, oracle, sqlite, xamarin, online-storage

I'm a novice in Xamarin.

I have already manage to store data locally with SQLite database. Now I want to add authentication and store the data online.

I'm looking for a simple tutorial that explains it simply (preferable with an app example)

I need:
- A Form page to create an account and a login
- A way to store the data on a server (MCS Oracle / or anything simple)
- A way to centralize all the data, if for instance many people have the app I can see their username and their data
- To handle forgotten passwords

Or if you have a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has a huge range of tutorials around this. Try this one:

https://github.com/MissionMarsFourthHorizon/operation-remote-resupply

Comment: Thanks, I have looked it, but it is not  what I am looking for

Comment: Doubt you'll find any one example hat does it all for you, you'll need to piece then together, that's why it's development.  This example covers the data to the cloud - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data

Comment: And this one covers authentication - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure/

Comment: @AndyFlisher , thanks ,Yes I cannot find all in one, a piece of them is okey